# How to get Tweets from the past 7 days from a certain country?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I'm trying to get tweets from a certain country from the past week (7 days is the limit from what I've read so far) but I can't seem to get a lot of results. Is this just because people don't have their geo tag turned on when they tweet? Or is something wrong with my code? I'm getting 44 when I run it now, but I feel like there are way more than 44 tweets in Kenya in the past week.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tweepy
import csv

# info
CONSUMER_KEY = '...'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '...'
ACCESS_TOKEN = '...'
ACCESS_SECRET = '...'
COUNTRY = 'Kenya'

# get authorization
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

# get tweets from country
place = api.geo_search(query=COUNTRY, granularity="country")
place_id = place[0].id

# print tweets and save to csv file
with open('tweets.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvFile:
    tweetWriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    tweets = api.search(q='place:%s' % place_id, count=100, since='1')
    count = 0
    for tweet in tweets:
        count += 1
        # tweet.id = unique id for tweet, text = text, place.name = where it was posted, created_at = UTC time
        tweetData = [tweet.id, tweet.user.name, tweet.text, tweet.place.name, tweet.created_at]
        tweetWriter.writerow(tweetData)

    print(count)
```

EDIT:
I couldn't seem to find a way to get more than the past 20-30 minutes worth of tweets from one country, I opted to use tweepy's stream and used coordinates to filter results out to a box around my country instead of trying to pull past data.

Comment: As a side note, the `since="1"` option is useless.

Comment: How would I make sure it would get all the past 7 days then instead of just a seemingly random selection from the past couple minutes?

Comment: According to the [REST API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search), "the Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published in the past 7 days. [...] If you want to match for completeness you should consider using a Streaming API instead."
The search function will return as much tweets as it can from the last seven days, ordered chronologically. You cannot specify directly in the search how old you want the tweets to be, but the 44 tweets you get are all there is.

Comment: I don't know much about geo in Twitter, maybe try something like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657555/how-to-restrict-the-results-of-a-twitter-search-to-one-country).

Comment: Thank you, it just seems weird to me that from the past 7 days all the tweets with location turned on happened in the past 15-20 minutes or so according to their created_at value. Even removing the 'since=1' gives me the same results

Comment: `since="1"` will match all tweets whose id is greater than 1. That is to say, all tweets.

Comment: I guess my question should be more directed at why all the results are only showing up for the past 15-20 minutes and how to get all the tweets from the past 7 days. Leaving in the 'since="1"' keeps all the tweets from only the past few minutes.